# How to not execute "onAddToSpace" when I add a OAUTH scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I'm trying to create a bot using GoogleChatAPI.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. If a User adds the bot that I'm creating, I want the bot to show a message of caution for using the bot.
2. If a User posts a message in the bot, the bot will post that message to another chat room.
   The method of posting a message is "UrlFetchApp.fetch" (and add an OAUTH scope at the same time)

To achieve task 1, I have used the code `onAddToSpace`.
To achieve task 2, I have used the code `onMessage`.

But when the Users add the bot, `onAddToSpace` does not get ignited. This event isn't in the Executions List.
But when I delete the code `UrlFetchApp.fetch` (and delete an OAUTH scope at the same time), then `onAddToSpace` gets ignited.

How can I write the codes to achieve the two things I'm trying to do at the same time?
Or is it even possible?

**Code:**

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var name = "";
  var message = "ご依頼承りました！情シスからご連絡いたしますので少々お待ち下さい。";
  postICTRoom(event);
  return { "text": message };
}

function onAddToSpace(event) {
  var message = "情シスへ質問、依頼ができるbotです。送信したメッセージは、ユーザー名付きですべて情シスチームチャットに送信されます。遊びが一切ないbotです、ご利用の際は十分ご注意ください。ここは万事屋ではありません。";
  return { "text": message };(*1)
}

function onRemoveFromSpace(event) {
  console.info("Bot removed from ",
      (event.space.name ? event.space.name : "this chat"));
}

function postICTRoom(event){
  var messageDate = new Date()  
  var url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/...";
  var thread = "spaces/..."
  var payload = {
    "text" : event.user.displayName + " " + Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, "JST", 'yyyy/MM/dd_HH:mm:ss') + "\n" + event.message.text,
    "thread": {
    "name": thread
    }
  }
  var json = JSON.stringify(payload);
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    "payload" : json
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "chat": {
  }
}
```

**OAuthScope**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
```

**Update**

1. `onAddToSpace` wasn't executed when I added the bot.
2. I posted a message and approved OAuth, then `onMessage` got executed.
3. After when I approved OAuth, and I once removed the bot, I added it again, `onAddToSpace` was already executed as I have expected...

I want to know if it is possible and if so, how I can get `onAddToSpace` executed before I have to approve OAuth.

**Update2**

Example of `onAddToSpace` successed(1)

1. Set scopes `script.external_request` and `chat`.
2. Added the bot.`onAddToSpace` was not executed at that time, because the log didn't display on screen and the bot didn't post a message(point of (*1) in Code).
3. Posted a message. `onMessage` successed. At that time I approved OAuth.
4. Removed the bot and added it again. `onAddToSpace` was executed the first time.

Example of `onAddToSpace` successed(2)

1. Removed scopes `script.external_request` and `chat`. And removed "UrlFetchApp.fetch".
2. Added the bot. `onAddToSpace` is executed from the beginning. Of course, It was not OAuth.
3. Posted a message. `onMessage` successed.

I'd like to get `onAddToSpace` to be executed at the point of successed(1)-Step2.
I don't know how I can make this work.

**Update3**

Manifest(modified):

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "chat": {
    "addToSpaceFallbackMessage": "情シスへ質問、依頼ができるbotです。送信したメッセージは、ユーザー名付きですべて情シスチームチャットに送信されます。遊びが一切ないbotです、ご利用の際は十分ご注意ください。ここは万事屋ではありません。"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show you manifest please?

Comment: Updated Manifest and OAuthScope

Answer (score 0):

### For correct functioning of your code you need to include the necessary OAuth scopes into the manifest

For this please modify your manifest as following:

```
{
"timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "chat": {
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I understand that you want to show a custom message before configuring your bot

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**This is not possible for security reasons**

- It is part of the Google OAuth authenticatication concept that your bot cannot anything (not even writing a message) before being authorized by the user
- As states int he [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#apps_script_bot_concepts)

> `onAddToSpace(e)`

> This function is executed when your bot is added to a space.

- Before you authorize the access you bot is **NOT** added to a space

**WORKAROUND**

- You can customize the OAuth2 concent screen in your GCP console

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

- Unfortunately there is no way to add a custom message to the consent screen, but you can include / set it as the Application name:

---

[image]

---

- After doing so, your content screen will look as following:

---

[image]

---

**HOW TO TEST**

In order to trigger authorization again

- Go on https://myaccount.google.com/security
- Third party apps with account access

[image]

---

[image]

---

- Remove your bot

---

[image]

---

- Now you can test authorization with the new consent screen

Comment: I have modified it.
But `onAddToSpace` did not get executed at the timing I wanted.

Comment: If you go on `View->Executions` - which error do you see?

Comment: No log. `onMessage` is logged that is success. `onAddToSpace` isn't logged. the log don't display on screen. `onAddToSpace` wasn't executed.

Comment: `onAddToSpace` will only be executed if you add the bot to a new chatroom (only once!). If only `onMessage` is executed, it means that `onAddToSpace` has already been run succesfully and the bot is already present in the room. To triggger `onAddToSpace` again, you need to create a new chatroom and add the bot to it.

Comment: I write the result of the verification about this problem in main post of question(Update2).

Comment: The solution you suggested may be a few different I want to do.
But, I read `https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#manifest_file` and I got to post a message before approving OAuth when I included `addToSpaceFallbackMessage` into the manifest!!(Update3)
Thank you, I have managed to make it work!
Apologies for slotting in Japanese in some parts which may have made it harder to understand.

Comment: Oh, this is also a great idea, I dif not know about this!